# Cannot escape single quotes in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, post

So, I am currently trying to POST a variable (string with spaces) to another php file.

The variable contains part of an SQL request `WHERE Row = 'something'`.

If I put single quotes around my variable it obviously throws an error because it doesn’t expect 'something'. If, however, I use double quotes, the single quotes around 'something' are changed to double quotes as well. How can I get this string posted?

```
function getAJAXlink( $count, $text) {

    if (!empty($this->sqlVariable)) {
      $addVarToLink = ", 'sqlVariable': '".$this->sqlVariable."' ";
    }

    if( $this->contentDiv == '')
        return '<a href="'. $this->anchorClass . ' ' . $this->baseURL . $count . '">'. $text .'</a>';

    $pageCount = $count?$count:0;
    $this->additionalParam = "{ 'page' : $pageCount $addVarToLink}";

    return "<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" " . $this->anchorClass . "
            onclick=\"$.post('". $this->baseURL."', ". $this->additionalParam .", function(data){
                   $('#". $this->contentDiv . "').html(data); }); return false;\">"
           . $text .'</a>';
}
```

returns: [image: Screenshot]

```
function getAJAXlink( $count, $text) {

    if (!empty($this->sqlVariable)) {
      $addVarToLink = ", 'sqlVariable': \"".$this->sqlVariable."\" ";
    }

    if( $this->contentDiv == '')
        return '<a href="'. $this->anchorClass . ' ' . $this->baseURL . $count . '">'. $text .'</a>';

    $pageCount = $count?$count:0;
    $this->additionalParam = "{ 'page' : $pageCount $addVarToLink}";

    return "<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" " . $this->anchorClass . "
            onclick=\"$.post('". $this->baseURL."', ". $this->additionalParam .", function(data){
                   $('#". $this->contentDiv . "').html(data); }); return false;\">"
           . $text .'</a>';
}
```

returns: [image: Screenshot]

Comment: Mixing ***four** languages* on *one line of code* is just begging for string quoting problems.  Surely you can separate these somehow?

Comment: Try using php [HEREDOC](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Comment: You should double quote the whole thing and forget about using single quotes. I found this helpful when working with html.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself. Heres the working code:

```
function getAJAXlink( $count, $text) {

    if (!empty($this->sqlVariable)) {
      $addVarToLink = ", 'sqlVariable': &quot;".$this->sqlVariable."&quot; ";
    }

    if( $this->contentDiv == '')
        return '<a href="'. $this->anchorClass . ' ' . $this->baseURL . $count . '">'. $text .'</a>';

    $pageCount = $count?$count:0;
    $this->additionalParam = "{ 'page' : $pageCount $addVarToLink}";

    return "<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" " . $this->anchorClass . "
            onclick=\"$.post('". $this->baseURL."', ". $this->additionalParam .", function(data){
                   $('#". $this->contentDiv . "').html(data); }); return false;\">"
           . $text .'</a>';
}
```